# searching all rows with specific column value in multiple files

Tags: c#, csv

I have `30+ comma separated` value file and each file contains `17000+ rows`. My requirement is to ***search of all the rows in all the files with a specific column value***.

Column value is coming from another `CSV file` which contains `5000+ rows` so in total I have to `search  5000+ distinct values` in above mentioned `30+ file` and `extract all the matching rows`.

**So far, My progress-**

***Take out columnValue from source***: I have used `string.Split()` to separate source file rows of and further I am splitting each row as `string[]` to extract the specific column value in loop(**5000+**).

***Read target files:*** while loading my application I read all the `30+ files` and storing rows in `Dictionary<string, string[]>` object as below-

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> data = new Dictionary<string, string[]>;
data.Add(fileName, fileRows); //storing 30+ file rows
```

***Search columnValue in target files:*** I am looping through `Dictionary` and reading every row of all the files to extract matching row if column value matches.

```
foreach(var col in colValues)
{
  foreach(var file in _data)
  {
    //split all the 17000+ rows and search for col
  }
  
}
```

Problem is its taking too much time to perform this operation as there is `5000+ values` to be search in `30+ files` and each file contains `17000+ rows`. In total, number of loops running are-

`5000 * 30 * 17000` which is quite large.

I am looking for some effective way to perform this search operation. Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't have option to import the file data in database tables?

Comment: Yes similar question as Chetan - this has to be done using C# to read the files directly? Especially if this is a recurring thing you'd be better off implementing a proper data solution, then this would be a simple SQL query away (which could also be issued via C#).

Comment: What data is in your csv files? Can any text-column contain the separator char or CR/LF? In other words, can you really use simple string.split operation on every row? You don't need a loop for your sought colValues. Build a Hashset from them and read every other file only once.